# Find List Of USB ports available on my Windows PC

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, usb, winusb

I have searched a lot and was unable to find the Answer for  the Query.
I wanted to find out how many USB ports are available in PC, i.e like for serial port we have "COM1" and "COM2". My PC (windows7) contains 8 USB ports I need to find the list of ports along with whether they are used or not used.

I have tried using WMI query with no result as it gives details of only connected devices and USB hubs only.

With Win DDK it will display all the ports available with each HUB but interestingly that is not the same as I see from outside. Win DDK will give how many ports are addressable from each hub not the exact no of ports visible from outside. Any C or C++  code would be of great help.

The ideal result would be something like this:

```
USB 1  USED
USB 2  Not USed 
USB 3  USED 
USB 4  Not Used 
.....
```

Comment: Maybe try libusb?  http://www.libusb.org/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine this. The simple reason is that you want to make a distinction between hubs inside your computer and hubs outside. It's likely that at least some of those 8 USB ports on your PC are linked to a hub soldered on your motherboard.

Also, it's not uncommon for USB to be used as an internal-only connection. E.g. many SD card readers are connected to an internal USB hub. To software, this looks like a USB port, but it's of course not visible on the outside of your PC.

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely true.  I think hubs and devices have flags that let the system know they are non-removable.  These flags can be used to determine whether a hub or device is on-board or external.

Comment: @ajs410: Too much grey area I suspect. Laptop docking stations? Technically a USB hub is allowed to set the removable bit on anything; the only guarantee is that you'll never see a device removal if the removable bit is not set. Still, could be worth a shot: the flag is at offset 7 in the bug class descriptor, and it's a per-port bitmask. Root hubs are usually non-removable, but that too is wrong for USB3 PC Express cards. (Their parent bus is PCI-e)